# Hide/show all series in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have like 50 different series, so by default, I have them hidden, so the user simply clicks on the ones he wants to see.

Sometimes, one wants to show all, or hide all, quickly. I cannot figure out how to toggle all on/off. Is this possible at all? I assume so, but cannot figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hide each series using `series.setVisible(false, false)`, [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setVisible()). - After all series will be hidden call `chart.redraw()` to redraw chart only once.

Comment: Where exactly is that supposed to be located? What is "series."? Is this outside the definition? How do I tell them apart?

Comment: I don't know where do you want to hide this series. Some extra button or so? Series is accessible via `chart.series`, and is an array, for example: `chart.series[0].setVisible(false);`. Did you open reference? There is an example..

Comment: The example only toggles a single one on/off... not all of them.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you or the example is talking about. I simply want to toggle all the series on/off with a button. How can it be clearer?

Comment: I think you don't even try to solve this on your own, and expecting someone else to write code for you. Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/68/

Comment: Actually, I *did* try with the information/knowledge I had, and failed. However, by you posting that example, I managed to adapt it to my situation and get it working. So you ended up helping me. So I thank you and vote you up.

Comment: (Or I guess I would have voted you up if I could. It requires "reputation points".)

Comment: I think to fully address the question, it would be helpful to note that chart.series is an array meaning that you can quickly loop through the array. So, combining Pawel's original answer you can simply do the following:
`for (var i =0; i < chart.series.length; i++){ chart.series[i].setVisible(false/true, false);
} 
chart.redraw();`

The important part, that Pawel's answer addresses, is the fact that with showing/hiding several series quickly, you only want the chart to be redrawn once, hence the second argument to `setVisibile` being false, and then explicitly calling chart.redraw() afterward

Answer (score 2):

this solution is based on http://jsfiddle.net/pGuEv/

```
  var chart = $('#chart-container').highcharts();
  var $hide_show_all_button = $('#hide_show_all_series_button');

  $hide_show_all_button.click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.visible) {
      $(chart.series).each(function(){
        this.setVisible(false, false);
      });
      chart.redraw();
      $hide_show_all_button.html('show all');
    } else {
      $(chart.series).each(function(){
        this.setVisible(true, false);
      });
      chart.redraw();
      $hide_show_all_button.html('hide all');
    }
  });
```